# Has the Sitecore Nuget feed been decommissioned or is it just down?

Tags: nuget

https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/

I cannot seem to hit the Sitecore Nuget feed at all.  It seems like the Sitecore Nuget feed is unreachable or does not exist anymore.

Comment: Looks like the issue is with myget.org as a whole.

Comment: https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1002999
See this

Comment: I changed it to new one and it's working